# how to delay a signal for several clock cycles in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

I'm trying to delay a signal for five clock cycles..

```
 process (read_clk)
begin
if (rising_edge(read_clk)) then
    rd_delay <= rd_en;
end if;
end process;

delay3 <= not(rd_en) and rd_delay;
```

By edge detecting technique,this will give me a one clock cycle delay, but i need five clock cycles.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signal `delay3` is *not* a delayed version of the signal `rd_en`, it is a pulse that is `'1'` for one clock cycle following a *falling edge* on the signal `rd_en`.

If you simple want to delay `rd_en` for five clock cycles, then add 5 flip-flops:

```
process (read_clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(read_clk) then
    rd_en_d5 <= rd_en_d4;
    rd_en_d4 <= rd_en_d3;
    rd_en_d3 <= rd_en_d2;
    rd_en_d2 <= rd_en_d1;
    rd_en_d1 <= rd_en;
  end if;
end process;
```

(Or if you have the VHDL knowledge do something a bit more elegant with an array and perhaps a for loop.)

If you then want to detect a falling edge as well, then go ahead and use something similar to the process in your question.

Comment: Hi @ Matthew Taylor, this idea works for me.. I got it.

Comment: Using individual named signals is not a good coding style nor a generic design approach.

Comment: @Paebbels I did allude to the fact that there are better ways of doing it in my answer, but I pitched the answer at best guess at the level of understanding of the questioner. I you have to ask how to delay a signal by 5 clock cycles, you're very much a beginner.

Comment: @MatthewTaylor if I want to delay it only by half a clock? supoose I have a clock of f1 = 2*f2 and I want to lauch clock f2 with half of clock f1 after I strart

Comment: @Yaakov You would use a flip-flip clocked off the opposite edge of the clock.

Answer (score 6):

The slightly more elegant version of Matthew's proposal could be, for instance:

```
constant dn: positive := 5;
signal delay: std_ulogic_vector(0 to dn - 1);
...
process (read_clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(read_clk) then
    delay <= rd_en & delay(0 to dn - 2);
  end if;
end process;
rd_en_d5 <= delay(dn - 1);
```

Comment: I've been thinking more on using `std_ulogic`, but I see the problem that `numeric_std` defines `signed` and `unsigned` as an array of `std_logic`. Thus you can quickly get mixed conventions in your code.

Comment: Not sure I understand your point. I also used `std_ulogic` (vector) in my answer. Anyway, about your remark on `signed` and `unsigned` being resolved, note that VHDL2008 (finally)  standardized `ieee.numeric_std.unresolved_signed` and `ieee.numeric_std.unresolved_unsigned`. It also defines the `u_signed` and `u_unsigned` aliases.

Comment: Thanks for the update; I did not see the new VHDL-2008 library parts yet. As for the rest, I was coming back to an earlier discussion we had on using `std_ulogic`. But it's clear now.